# How to use param passing in Lambda / API Gateway

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to build an API using API Gateway, Lambda, and RDS. So you type in the URL and get the specific rows from RDS back in a JSON format.

**So this is what I would like to achieve.**

- /production/myfootballapi?table=football -> all rows in the table
  should be returned (not working)
- /production/myfootballapi?table=football&id=2 -> only the id 2 row
  should be returned (only this case works)

The main problem that I am having is that I currently can't show all rows because I always have to define the id otherwise an error occurs.

My API Gateway Body Mapping Template:

```
{
"table" : "$input.params('table')",
"id" : $input.params('id')
}
```

My Lambda function

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var config = require('./config.json');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
host     : config.dbhost,
user     : config.dbuser,
password : config.dbpassword,
database : config.dbname,
});


exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {


//prevent timeout from waiting event loop
context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
if (err) throw err; 
// Use the connection

var table = event.table;
var id = event.id;

// This if-function is just a try to solve this problem but it doesn't work
if (id !== null) { 
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id = ?";
  var inserts = [table, id];

} else {
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?";
  var inserts = table;
}

sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
  // And done with the connection.
  connection.release();
  // Handle error after the release.
  if (error) callback(error);
  else callback(null,results);
  });
});
};
```

If you need further information, please leave a comment.

THANKS!

Comment: My 2 cents, I am not sure about that: the API Gateway Body Mapping Template expects 2 params: `table` and `id`, or you only provide one in the first case.

Comment: What error occurs when you don't define id? Could you post it in its own section?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil I get an "{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'}\' (code 125)): expected a value\n at [Source: [B@30328d38; line: 4, column: 2]"}"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, many thanks to everyone for helping me. I fixed it myself but I will also document this if someone has a similar question.

**> API Gateway <**

*Go to Integration Request*

[image: go to Integration Request]

Add the following Body Mapping Template

[image]

```
{
#set($queryMap = $input.params().querystring)

#foreach( $key in $queryMap.keySet())
  "$key" : "$queryMap.get($key)"
  #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
#end
}
```

*Go to Method Request*

[image]

*Add the parameters*
[image]

**> Lambda <**

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var config = require('./config.json');

var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : config.dbhost,
    user     : config.dbuser,
    password : config.dbpassword,
    database : config.dbname,
  });


exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {

  //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err; 
    // Use the connection

   var table = event.table;
   var id = event.id;

    if (isNaN(id)) { 
       var sql = "SELECT * FROM ??";
       var inserts = table;
     } else {
       var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id = ?";
       var inserts = [table, id];
     }

    sql = mysql.format(sql, inserts);

  connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
      // And done with the connection.
      connection.release();
      // Handle error after the release.
      if (error) callback(error);
      else callback(null,results);
    });
  });
};
```

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/compute/using-api-gateway-mapping-templates-to-handle-changes-in-your-back-end-apis/

I think, it is probably not the best code in lambda but it works for now. I will improve it later. :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may be your `if (id !== null)` statement.  I mocked up your example, added `console.log(sql);` and found that even when no id was sent in the request, the SQL query returned was `SELECT * FROM '\"Customer\"' WHERE id = NULL`.

I changed your if statement to the following.

```js
if (id) { 
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id = ?";
  var inserts = [table, id];

} else {
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?";
  var inserts = table;
}
```

After making this change, the SQL query was `SELECT * FROM '\"Customer\"'` as expected when no ID is in the request.

For completeness, I did make one other modification.  I did not use the Body Mapping Template at all.  I used the "Use Lambda Proxy Integration" setting in the Integration Request configuration instead.  This will eliminate the need to use Body Mapping Templates.

[image]

In the Method Request configuration, define the URL Query String Parameters

[image]

In your Lambda function, you will be able to access your table and id as `event.queryStringParameters.table` and `event.queryStringParameters.id` respectively.  Then perform whatever actions you want in your Lambda function.

```js
var table = JSON.stringify(event.queryStringParameters.table);
var id = JSON.stringify(event.queryStringParameters.id);

console.log("Table: " + table);
console.log("ID: " +id);
```

----------- EDITED ---------------

Make sure your callback in your Lambda function sends a valid response that can be handled by the API gateway.  Here is how I formatted my sample code that I mocked up to test this.

```js
var response = {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "my_header": "my_value"
    },
    "body": JSON.stringify(results),
    "isBase64Encoded": false
};
callback(null, response);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I changed everthing to your recommendation and deploy API. I get an "{"message": "Internal server error"} with Id and without

Comment: I'll take a look at my code when I get back home later tonight.  In the meantime, just make sure that you are return a valid JSON object in your response from Lambda.

Comment: It is most likely a malformed response.  I've updated my answer to include the format that I used in my mocked up test of your situation.  Additional information can be found here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/malformed-502-api-gateway/  You may want to enable logging on your API gateway and look through CloudWatch if you continue to see errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mapping template is probably too simple. If you get that to work I'd love to know how because my template requires a great deal of code and it was a pain to get right but I've accepted it. I think without more processing you'll probably run into other issues when certain values or put into your parameters. You'll have to deal with escaping etc etc.

This is the template I use to map API gateway to lambda. I pulled it out of my cloudformation template so forgive me if random json or extra quotes are still present. If you rather see the cloudformation template I can show that.

```
#set($allParams = $input.params()) {
       \"params\" : {
                #foreach($type in $allParams.keySet())
                #set($params = $allParams.get($type))
                \"$type\" : {
                    #foreach($paramName in $params.keySet())
                   \"$paramName\" : 
                   \"$util.escapeJavaScript($params.get($paramName))\
                    if($foreach.hasNext),#end\
                   #end
                }\
                #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
                #end\
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `if-else` statement to :

```
if (id !== "") { 
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE id = ?";
  var inserts = [table, id];
} else {
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM ?";
  var inserts = table;
}
```

Since you have set the body mapping template the `id` will be set to `""` when you don't pass it as parameter. You can see its value in logs or you can try to log the `id` before you enter the `if-else` statement.